# How to fix Python installation on Windows?

Tags: python, windows

I've already installed (on my Win10) the `Python 3.9.12` using the installer(32-bit). During the setup I've checked to add python to system path. The installation reported as suspenseful, BUT when I type "py -version" or "python -version" i get error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python39-32\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\ÔÇô-version': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

This same happens with 64-bit version to. The error remains no matter if it's installed as admin or regular user
Please Help!

P.S.
This same also happens with other `py` versions like 3.9.2 or so...

Comment: Try `--version` instead of `-version`

Comment: Python 3.9 is deprecated, it has reached its end of support, new users should not try Python 3.9, instead, use Python 3.11. And why are you using 32-bit programs? You should use 64-bit version instead.

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος Python 3.9 is still in support until October 2025: https://devguide.python.org/versions/. But anyone doing a new Python install indeed should go for 3.11 unless they have some specific reason for needing a lower version.